# Storing output in a textfile in PIG

Tags: apache-pig

I need to store the final output in PIG in a text file.

My requirement is:

Let `'Test'` be the final output file and i need to store it in a path.
say, `'/path/'`

My code:

```
a = LOAD 'example.csv' USING PigStorage(';');

b = FOREACH a GENERATE $0,$1,$2,$3,$6,$7,$8,$9,$11,$12,$13,$14,$20,$24,$25;

STORE b INTO ‘myoutput’;
```

when i am trying to save the final it is getting saved as partfile.
But i need to load this output in another relation. 
If i am able to save it as a text file i can load it  but can i use the part file in loading?
please suggest to save output in text file.

Comment: yes you can load part file in another relation, in another script.
you are getting confused with *.txt extension and text file format.
by default if you store USING PigStorage() it will save in TEXT file format, which you can read

Answer (score 0):

> Understand STORE command loads to a file.   refer this tutorial  :
>   https://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.7.0/piglatin_ref2.html#STORE

```
STORE b INTO ‘myoutput.txt’ using PigStorage(',');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex * to load the stored relation.

```
STORE b INTO '/path/' USING PigStorage(',');
```

and load it like this

```
a = LOAD '/path/part-*' INTO USING PigStorage(',');
```

Comment: Thanks. I am loading it using only the directory name and it is fetching the data.